# assymetric-spacing colon as middle separator in set comprehension at various sizes

Tags: symbols, punctuation, newtxmath, tex-gyre-math, bigdelim

Let's assume within this post that an author unconventionally insists on using the colon as a middle separation symbol in all three traditional variable binders (class/set comprehensions, quantifier expressions, lambda-terms):

> {x: (x)}

> ∀ x: (x)

> λ x: g(x)

Notice that above, there's no spacing before the colon even in set comprehensions.
How do we implement this in LaTeX in the best™ way? In particular, what to do when the braces are large (e.g., because the part before or after the colon is internally large, say, because it contains (nested) braces itself)? As the colon is part of the set/class comprehension, we set this colon in the same size as the set comprehension; which spacing around the colon would be proper™?

Here is some code to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[textheight=22cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]
  \setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand{\biggg}{\bBigg@\thr@@}
  \newcommand{\Biggg}{\bBigg@{3.5}}
  \makeatother
\else
  \usepackage[helvratio=.9]{newtxtext}
  \usepackage[slantedGreek,subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand{\biggg}{\bBigg@{3.07766}}%%% for NewTX fonts
  \newcommand{\Biggg}{\bBigg@{3.56997}}%%% for NewTX fonts
  \makeatother
\fi
\def\bigggl{\mathopen\biggg}
\def\bigggm{\mathrel\biggg}
\def\bigggr{\mathclose\biggg}
\def\Bigggl{\mathopen\Biggg}
\def\Bigggm{\mathrel\Biggg}
\def\Bigggr{\mathclose\Biggg}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}[3]{#1 x\in X#2 \forall\,y\in Y\colon #3}
\begin{gather*}
  \test{\{}{\colon}{\varphi\}}\\
  \test{\bigl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[1.2]{$:$}}}}}{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}}\\
  \test{\bigl\{}{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[1.2]{$\colon$}}}}{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}}\\
  \test{\bigl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[1.2]{$\colon$}}}}}{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}}\\
  \test{\Bigl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[1.8]{$:$}}}}}{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}}\\
  \test{\Bigl\{}{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[1.8]{$\colon$}}}}{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}}\\
  \test{\Bigl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[1.8]{$\colon$}}}}}{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}}\\
  \test{\biggl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[2.4]{$:$}}}}}{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}}\\
  \test{\biggl\{}{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[2.4]{$\colon$}}}}{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}}\\
  \test{\biggl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[2.4]{$\colon$}}}}}{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}}\\
  \test{\Biggl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[3]{$:$}}}}}{\dotso\biggl\{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}\dotso\Biggr\}}\\
  \test{\Biggl\{}{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[3]{$\colon$}}}}{\dotso\biggl\{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}\dotso\Biggr\}}\\
  \test{\Biggl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[3]{$\colon$}}}}}{\dotso\biggl\{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}\dotso\Biggr\}}\\
  \test{\bigggl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[3.6]{$:$}}}}}{\dotso\Biggl\{\dotso\biggl\{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}\dotso\Biggr\}\dotso\bigggr\}}\\
  \test{\bigggl\{}{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[3.6]{$\colon$}}}}{\dotso\Biggl\{\dotso\biggl\{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}\dotso\Biggr\}\dotso\bigggr\}}\\
  \test{\bigggl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[3.6]{$\colon$}}}}}{\dotso\Biggl\{\dotso\biggl\{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}\dotso\Biggr\}\dotso\bigggr\}}\\
  \test{\Bigggl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[4.2]{$:$}}}}}{\dotso\bigggl\{\dotso\Biggl\{\dotso\biggl\{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}\dotso\Biggr\}\dotso\bigggr\}\dotso\Bigggr\}}\\
  \test{\Bigggl\{}{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[4.2]{$\colon$}}}}{\dotso\bigggl\{\dotso\Biggl\{\dotso\biggl\{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}\dotso\Biggr\}\dotso\bigggr\}\dotso\Bigggr\}}\\
  \test{\Bigggl\{}{\mathpunct{\vcenter{\hbox{\textlarger[4.2]{$\colon$}}}}}{\dotso\bigggl\{\dotso\Biggl\{\dotso\biggl\{\dotso\Bigl\{\dotso\bigl\{\dotso\{\dotso\}\dotso\bigr\}\dotso\Bigr\}\dotso\biggr\}\dotso\Biggr\}\dotso\bigggr\}\dotso\Bigggr\}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

By the way, why is there so much vertical space between first and second lines?

Comment: You just use the ordinary colon at its ordinary size. What else?

Comment: @egreg Technically, the colon is part of the set/class comprehension, so the colon should be set in its size. Moreover, the ordinary colon is a Rel and therefore typically has symmetric spacing, whereas the author specifically wishes assymetric spacing: less spacing before, more spacing after. (We don't wish to argue about how “clever” this choice is.)

Comment: WIth “ordinary colon” I was referring to the glyph, not to its possible atom type. But if you like to use ambiguous (the colon used with two different meanings) and ugly (in the enlarged version) notation…

Comment: @AlbertNash unicode-math has `\mathcolon` for : (U+003A) and `\mathratio` for ∶ (U+2236) or of course you can use either character directly. No sure what you mean by always using 2236?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mean that both `:` and `\colon` also produce ∶ (U+2236) in the given MWE if complied with lualatex. I suspect that this redefinition comes from unicode-math. Comment corrected.

Comment: @egreg Let's say, the author would like to use it (in this question, I act as a typesetter only). His purpose is unifying the notation of the middle separator in variable-binding expressions, so ambiguity in this particular case is even intentional, whether we like it or not. As for the enlarged version, we have to do it as explained above (not sure whether it is ugly or beautiful; I'd say you are simply not used to it). By the way, the colon exists both as : (U+003A) and ∶ (U+2236), and math-unicode seems to output the latter (for whichever reason) for `:` or `\colon` in our source code.

Comment: @AlbertNash sorry you are right, it does `\__um_remap_symbol:nnn {\`\:} {\mathrel} {"02236}% colon to ratio (i.e., punct to rel)` user settable option: `\usepackage[colon=literal]{unicode-math}`